# IMO 2019: Find all functions $f: \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ such that $f(2a) + 2\, f(b) = f \big( f (a+b)\big)$.

Tags: functions, contest-math, problem-solving, functional-equations, integers

**Source:** International Mathematical Olympiads, 2019.

The question is:

> Let $\mathbb{Z}$ be the set of integers. Find all functions  $f: \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ such that, for all integers $a$ and $b$, the following is true 
>   $$f(2a) + 2\,f(b) = f\big(f (a+b)\big)\,.$$

I only managed to do this:

Suppose some function *f* has the form : *f(x)= n.x* ( with n, integer).

We would get :

*n(2a)+ 2(nb) = n(n(a+b))*

--> *2na + 2nb = n²(a+b)*

--> *2n (a+b)  = n²(a+b)*    ( Dividing by a + b, provided a+b is not equal to 0)

--> *2 n = n²*

--> *n² = 2 n*

--> *n = 2*.    ( Although I wonder whether dividing by number *n* is legal, even if *n* is not 0)

So, apparently, if a function satisfying the *f*-conditions has form *f(x)= n.x*, then

this function must have form *f(x) = 2x*.

However, apparently, f must have any sum ( a + b) in its domain, in order to be from Z to Z; for the expression *f( a+b)* featured in the expression defining *f*.  But, while solving the equation, I excluded the case in which *(a+b)= O*. Notwithsatnding *(0 + 0)* is a sum of integers.

So, my hypothesis fails, and ***I am left with a negative conclusion*** :

there is no function *f* ( satisfying the *f* formula)  such that f(x) = n.x.

Comment: the set of functions you are considering is only a very small subset of possible functions from $\mathbb{Z}$ to itself.

Comment: I think you meant that the set I considered myself is too small , or did you mean that the set of f-functions ( satisfying the requisit) is actually small?

Comment: The constant function $f(x)=0$ and the linear function $f(x)=2x+k$ are solutions.  And a user with this many reputation points can perhaps use mathjax to post questions, no?

Comment: the set you considered is too small.

Comment: @Thomas.- Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Hint: try to show $f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)+k$ so that $f(x)+k$ is linear for some $k$ (relate it to $f(0)$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We say that $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ satisfies the condition $P(a,b)$ for some integers $a$ and $b$ if $$f(2a)+2\,f(b)=f\big(f(a+b)\big)\,.$$
We want to find all functions $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ such that $f$ has the property $P(a,b)$ for every $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$.  We shall prove that either $f(n)=0$ for every integer $n$, or there exists a constant $c\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(n)=2n+c$ for each integer $n$.

Let $c:=f(0)$.  For arbitrary $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$, the conditions $P(a,b)$ and $P(b,a)$ implies
$$f(2a)+2\,f(b)=f\big(f(a+b)\big)=f\big(f(b+a)\big)=f(2b)+2\,f(a)\,,$$
whence
$$f(2a)-f(2b)=2\big(f(a)-f(b)\big)$$ for every $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$.  In particular, when $b:=0$, we get
$$f(2a)=2f(a)-c\tag{*}$$
for all integers $a$.  Therefore, using (*), $P(a,b)$ becomes
$$f\big(f(a+b)\big)=2\,f(a)+2\,f(b)-c\tag{$\star$}$$
for all $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$.  In particular, with $b:=0$ in ($\star$), we get
$$f\big(f(a)\big)=2\,f(a)+c\tag{#}$$
for every $a\in\mathbb{Z}$.  From (#) and ($\star$), we have
$$f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)-c\,.$$
Let $g(n):=f(n)-c$ for every integer $n$.  The equation above can be rewritten as
$$g(a+b)=g(a)+g(b)$$
for every $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$. This is Cauchy's functional equation, and the solutions are well known to be $g(n)=kn$ for some constant $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.  That is, $$f(n)=g(n)+c=kn+c$$
for some integer constants $k$ and $c$.  Now, we must check the property $P(a,b)$.  That is, for all integers $a$ and $b$,
$$\big(k(2a)+c\big)+2\big(kb+c\big)=f(2a)+2\,f(b)=f\big(f(a+b)\big)=k\big(k(a+b)+c\big)+c\,.$$
Hence, 
$$2k(a+b)+3c=k^2(a+b)+(k+1)c$$
for all $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$  Thus,
$$(k-2)\big(k(a+b)-c\big)=0$$
for all $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$.  This implies:

- $k=2$, or
- $k(a+b)=c$ for all $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$.

In the former case, $f(n)=2n+c$ for all integers $n$, which is easily seen to be a solution.  In the latter case, $k=c=0$ is the only possibility, so $f(n)=0$ for all integers $n$, which is obviously  solution.

**Remark.**  Here is a generalization, a proof of which is obtained largely by the same argument as above.  Suppose that $I$ is an integral domain.  Let a nonempty set $S\subseteq I$  and a nonzero scalar $\lambda\in I$ be such that

- $S$ is closed under addition (i.e., $S$ is an additive subsemigroup of $I$),
- $S$ is closed under multiplication by $\lambda$,
- if $h:S\to I$ satisfies Cauchy's functional equation $h(x+y)=h(x)+h(y)$ for all $x,y\in S$, then there exists $\mu\in I$ such that $h(x)=\mu x$ for all $x\in S$.

The solutions $f:S\to S$ such that
$$f(\lambda x)+\lambda\,f(y)=f\big(f(x+y)\big)$$
for all $x,y\in S$ are

- $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in S$ in the case that $0\in S$, and
- $f(x)=\lambda x+c$ for all $x\in S$, where $c\in I$ is a constant such that $\lambda x+c\in S$ for any $x\in S$.

In the setting where $I=\mathbb{C}$, the set $S$ can be $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$, $\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$, $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{Q}_{\geq 0}$, $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, or $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$.  In fact, $S$ can be any additive subsemigroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$, or any divisible additive subsemigroup of $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ or $\mathbb{R}_{\leq 0}$ will do.  An obvious choice of $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}$ that works for all $S$ is a positive integer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's aim for a really short solution. For $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ we have
$$f(2)+2f(n)=f(f(n+1))=f(0)+2f(n+1).$$
Because $f(n+1)-f(n)=\frac{f(2)-f(0)}{2}$ is independent of $n$ the function $f$ is linear. It remains to check that $f(n):=A+B\cdot n$ satisfies the original equation for arbitrary $A\in\mathbb{Z}$ and only for $B\in\left\{0,2\right\}$.